# Designer showing: Invalid Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

Hello I have to examples where the deployed code works without any error, but the designer complaints.

My search around for this type of error refers to the fact that the project name has "spaces" or old versions of the phone.controls. Neither are the issue for me. I am therefore thinking it might be a change in template structure ? I have 3 examples both giving the error:

**Example 1**

```
<ListBox Canvas.ZIndex="1001" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ColorPickerListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ColorList}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangeColourCommand, ElementName=ColorPickerListBox}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="{Binding color}">

                                    </Rectangle>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="10"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

**Example 2**

```
<View:CanvasItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DecorationOnShield}">
            <View:CanvasItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </View:CanvasItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </View:CanvasItemsControl>
```

**Example 3**

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FFFFE5CD" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Path_6" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FFFFE5CD" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Rectangle_7" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Viewbox Margin="-10,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Viewbox.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
                            </Viewbox.RenderTransform>
                            <Grid Height="60" Width="109">
                                <Viewbox x:Name="Group" Width="108.952" Height="60.3575">
                                    <Viewbox Height="49" Width="103">
                                        <Grid Height="58.5920524596841" Width="114.358690261841">
                                            <Viewbox x:Name="Group1" Width="107.672" Height="16.0729" Margin="0,43,6,0">
                                                <Canvas Width="107.672" Height="16.0729">
                                                    <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle1" Width="83.1734" Height="14.4729" Canvas.Left="15.6519" Canvas.Top="0.799988" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF733800"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path1" Width="36.1823" Height="4.64556" Canvas.Left="14.9854" Canvas.Top="6.83045" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB65900" Data="F1 M 15.3054,8.42395C 18.6213,8.42395 25.7329,8.47461 28.5751,8.03607C 31.4174,7.59753 51.3131,6.0625 50.8394,8.47473C 50.3657,10.8868 45.1549,11.3254 38.523,11.1061C 31.8911,10.8868 30.6373,10.33 15.4787,10.33"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_15" Width="39.3557" Height="7.28494" Canvas.Left="15.1587" Canvas.Top="5.56275" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF4A2500" Data="F1 M 15.4787,7.21094C 22.1106,7.21094 29.0489,7.15894 33.7859,6.28186C 38.523,5.40466 55.1028,5.84326 54.1553,8.91327C 53.2079,11.9833 40.8915,12.8604 31.4174,12.4218C 21.9432,11.9833 23.058,11.4968 15.4787,11.7162"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_18" Width="42.4594" Height="9.32969" Canvas.Left="15.3319" Canvas.Top="4.50856" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB65900" Data="F1 M 15.6519,5.47815C 23.705,5.25891 40.4178,4.52753 46.1023,4.96606C 51.7868,5.40466 57.4713,6.93964 57.4713,8.69397C 57.4713,10.4482 48.4709,13.5182 43.2601,13.5182C 38.0492,13.5183 18.9679,12.7558 15.6519,12.7559"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_20" Width="6.85588" Height="2.21011" Canvas.Left="39.0928" Canvas.Top="7.91791" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB65900" Fill="#FF5B2D00" Data="F1 M 45.6287,9.57123C 45.6288,9.57123 44.3729,8.36206 43.7438,8.25555C 43.1148,8.14893 38.8722,8.53601 39.4705,9.13269C 40.0687,9.72943 45.598,10.0614 45.6287,9.57123 Z "/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_21" Width="6.85587" Height="2.2101" Canvas.Left="63.2515" Canvas.Top="7.03786" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB65900" Fill="#FF5B2D00" Data="F1 M 69.7874,8.69116C 69.7874,8.69116 68.5316,7.48206 67.9025,7.37549C 67.2735,7.26892 63.0309,7.65594 63.6292,8.25262C 64.2274,8.84937 69.7567,9.18134 69.7874,8.69116 Z "/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_22" Width="14.1696" Height="4.74651" Canvas.Left="59.8778" Canvas.Top="5.80243" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF5B2D00" Data="F1 M 65.998,10.2289C 64.5,10.229 59.3661,8.91327 60.3135,8.03607C 61.2609,7.15894 67.4192,5.62396 68.8403,6.28186C 70.2614,6.9397 74.5823,7.4801 73.5773,8.25537C 72.1562,9.35181 67.4191,10.229 65.998,10.2289 Z "/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_23" Width="20.0949" Height="6.93487" Canvas.Left="58.0987" Canvas.Top="4.49127" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB65900" Data="F1 M 59.3661,5.62396C 61.0383,5.10791 65.0507,4.52753 69.314,4.96606C 73.5773,5.40466 78.3145,7.15894 77.8407,7.81683C 77.367,8.47473 72.1563,11.1061 69.7877,11.1061C 67.4191,11.1061 59.3661,10.4482 58.8924,9.79041C 58.4187,9.13251 57.945,6.06262 59.3661,5.62396 Z "/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_24" Width="83.9867" Height="4.72045" Canvas.Left="15.1587" Canvas.Top="3.33039" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF4A2500" Data="F1 M 15.4787,4.4386C 18.3209,4 24.3118,3.65033 32.8385,3.65039C 41.3652,3.65039 53.6816,4.52753 55.1028,4.96606C 56.5239,5.40466 59.3661,4.52753 60.7872,4.30823C 62.2084,4.08899 72.1562,3.86963 77.367,5.40466C 82.5778,6.9397 79.2761,7.22693 93.9468,7.59753L 98.8254,7.73083"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_25" Width="83.4669" Height="6.91535" Canvas.Left="15.5052" Canvas.Top="8.11652" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF4A2500" Data="F1 M 15.8252,14.3154C 21.036,14.5347 49.4183,15.4918 53.6816,13.299C 57.945,11.1061 59.3661,11.5446 63.1558,11.9833C 66.9454,12.4218 79.7356,10.4482 83.0515,9.13251C 86.3674,7.81689 98.6521,8.77045 98.6521,8.77045"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_26" Width="83.6401" Height="4.56681" Canvas.Left="15.1587" Canvas.Top="2.04611" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB65900" Data="F1 M 15.4787,3.05237C 25.9002,2.61377 49.892,1.67676 54.1553,3.65039C 58.4187,5.62396 58.4187,1.01898 70.7351,2.77319C 83.0515,4.52759 82.5778,6.28186 88.736,6.28186C 94.8942,6.28192 98.4788,6.34448 98.4788,6.17133"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_27" Width="44.3626" Height="5.48682" Canvas.Left="54.7828" Canvas.Top="9.44786" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB65900" Data="F1 M 55.1028,14.6147C 55.1028,14.6147 57.4713,12.4218 60.7873,12.8604C 64.1032,13.299 83.0515,10.8868 85.8937,10.229C 88.736,9.57123 98.8254,9.81018 98.8254,9.81018"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_28" Width="15.458" Height="2.02624" Canvas.Left="15.3319" Canvas.Top="0.47968" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF4A2500" Data="F1 M 15.6519,2.18591C 18.4942,2.18591 30.47,0.799683 30.47,0.799683"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_29" Width="23.0458" Height="5.04474" Canvas.Left="76.0996" Canvas.Top="0.47968" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF4A2500" Data="F1 M 76.4196,0.799683C 76.4196,0.799683 85.8938,4.74677 88.736,4.74677C 91.5782,4.74683 93.1409,5.61615 98.8254,4.95837"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_30" Width="10.5879" Height="3.27141" Canvas.Left="88.416" Canvas.Top="0.47968" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB25700" Data="F1 M 88.736,0.799683C 88.736,0.799683 91.1046,3.21179 98.6839,3.43109"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_31" Width="37.257" Height="4.25" Canvas.Left="61.8884" Canvas.Top="11.1232" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF4A2500" Data="F1 M 62.2084,15.0532C 62.2084,15.0532 71.2088,13.9568 76.4196,13.0797C 81.6304,12.2026 93.1409,11.1044 98.8254,11.543"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_32" Width="13.0979" Height="2.68285" Canvas.Left="86.0475" Canvas.Top="13.129" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB65900" Data="F1 M 86.3675,15.4918C 86.3675,15.4918 90.2987,13.4489 98.8254,13.449"/>
                                                    <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle_1" Width="84.9467" Height="16.0729" Canvas.Left="14.6786" Canvas.Top="-1.01924e-005" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1.6" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000"/>
                                                </Canvas>
                                            </Viewbox>
                                            <Viewbox x:Name="Group_16" Width="107.672" Height="16.0728" Margin="0,28,6,15">
                                                <Canvas Width="107.672" Height="16.0728">
                                                    <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle_17" Width="83.1734" Height="14.4729" Canvas.Left="15.6519" Canvas.Top="0.799927" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF733800"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_33" Width="36.1823" Height="4.64552" Canvas.Left="14.9854" Canvas.Top="6.83047" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB65900" Data="F1 M 15.3054,8.42389C 18.6213,8.42389 25.7329,8.47461 28.5751,8.03613C 31.4174,7.59753 51.3131,6.06256 50.8394,8.47467C 50.3657,10.8868 45.1549,11.3254 38.523,11.1061C 31.8911,10.8868 30.6373,10.33 15.4787,10.33"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_34" Width="39.3557" Height="7.28502" Canvas.Left="15.1587" Canvas.Top="5.56273" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF4A2500" Data="F1 M 15.4787,7.211C 22.1106,7.211 29.0489,7.159 33.7859,6.2818C 38.523,5.40466 55.1028,5.84326 54.1553,8.91321C 53.2079,11.9833 40.8915,12.8604 31.4174,12.4219C 21.9432,11.9833 23.058,11.4969 15.4787,11.7162"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_35" Width="40.9735" Height="9.32975" Canvas.Left="15.3319" Canvas.Top="4.50856" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB65900" Data="F1 M 15.6519,5.47815C 23.705,5.25885 40.4178,4.52747 46.1023,4.96613C 51.7868,5.40466 55.9854,6.97742 55.9854,8.73175C 55.9854,10.4861 48.4709,13.5182 43.2601,13.5183C 38.0492,13.5183 18.9679,12.7559 15.6519,12.7559"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_36" Width="6.85588" Height="2.2101" Canvas.Left="39.0929" Canvas.Top="7.91786" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB65900" Fill="#FF5B2D00" Data="F1 M 45.6288,9.57117C 45.6288,9.57117 44.373,8.36206 43.7439,8.25549C 43.1148,8.14893 38.8722,8.53595 39.4706,9.13263C 40.0688,9.72937 45.5981,10.0613 45.6288,9.57117 Z "/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_37" Width="14.1637" Height="2.85962" Canvas.Left="59.8821" Canvas.Top="6.54972" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF5B2D00" Data="F1 M 66.2254,9.05176C 64.7274,9.05182 59.3661,8.91321 60.3135,8.03613C 61.2609,7.159 67.3643,6.47388 68.7854,7.13171C 70.2065,7.78961 74.5823,7.4801 73.5773,8.25543C 72.1562,9.35181 67.6465,9.05182 66.2254,9.05176 Z "/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_38" Width="19.7231" Height="6.12216" Canvas.Left="58.4712" Canvas.Top="5.30393" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB65900" Data="F1 M 61.1054,6.17175C 62.7776,5.65576 65.162,5.41321 69.4254,5.85181C 73.6887,6.29034 78.3145,7.15894 77.8407,7.81677C 77.367,8.47473 72.1563,11.1061 69.7877,11.1061C 67.4191,11.1061 59.3661,10.4482 58.8924,9.79041C 58.4187,9.13257 59.6843,6.61041 61.1054,6.17175 Z "/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_39" Width="83.9867" Height="4.72039" Canvas.Left="15.1587" Canvas.Top="3.33039" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF4A2500" Data="F1 M 15.4787,4.43854C 18.3209,4 24.3118,3.65039 32.8385,3.65039C 41.3652,3.65039 53.6816,4.52747 55.1028,4.96613C 56.5239,5.40466 59.3661,4.52747 60.7872,4.30823C 62.2084,4.08899 72.1562,3.86963 77.367,5.40466C 82.5778,6.93976 79.2761,7.22693 93.9468,7.59753L 98.8254,7.73077"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_40" Width="83.4669" Height="6.91532" Canvas.Left="15.5052" Canvas.Top="8.11655" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF4A2500" Data="F1 M 15.8252,14.3154C 21.036,14.5347 49.4183,15.4918 53.6816,13.299C 57.945,11.1061 59.3661,11.5447 63.1558,11.9833C 66.9454,12.4219 79.7356,10.4482 83.0515,9.13257C 86.3674,7.81689 98.6521,8.77051 98.6521,8.77051"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_41" Width="83.6401" Height="4.56676" Canvas.Left="15.1587" Canvas.Top="2.04613" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB65900" Data="F1 M 15.4787,3.05231C 25.9002,2.61377 49.892,1.67682 54.1553,3.65039C 58.4187,5.62402 58.4187,1.01892 70.7351,2.77325C 83.0515,4.52759 82.5778,6.2818 88.736,6.2818C 94.8942,6.28186 98.4788,6.34454 98.4788,6.17126"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_42" Width="44.3626" Height="5.48682" Canvas.Left="54.7828" Canvas.Top="9.44781" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB65900" Data="F1 M 55.1028,14.6146C 55.1028,14.6146 57.4713,12.4218 60.7873,12.8604C 64.1032,13.299 83.0515,10.8868 85.8937,10.229C 88.736,9.57117 98.8254,9.81012 98.8254,9.81012"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_43" Width="15.458" Height="2.02624" Canvas.Left="15.3319" Canvas.Top="0.47968" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF4A2500" Data="F1 M 15.6519,2.18591C 18.4942,2.18591 30.47,0.799683 30.47,0.799683"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_44" Width="23.0458" Height="5.04483" Canvas.Left="76.0996" Canvas.Top="0.479619" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF4A2500" Data="F1 M 76.4196,0.799622C 76.4196,0.799622 85.8938,4.74683 88.736,4.74683C 91.5782,4.74683 93.1409,5.61621 98.8254,4.95837"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_45" Width="10.5879" Height="3.27141" Canvas.Left="88.416" Canvas.Top="0.479619" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB25700" Data="F1 M 88.736,0.799622C 88.736,0.799622 91.1046,3.21179 98.6839,3.43103"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_46" Width="37.257" Height="4.25009" Canvas.Left="61.8884" Canvas.Top="11.1232" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF4A2500" Data="F1 M 62.2084,15.0533C 62.2084,15.0533 71.2088,13.9568 76.4196,13.0797C 81.6304,12.2025 93.1409,11.1043 98.8254,11.543"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_47" Width="13.0979" Height="2.68285" Canvas.Left="86.0475" Canvas.Top="13.129" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB65900" Data="F1 M 86.3675,15.4918C 86.3675,15.4918 90.2987,13.449 98.8254,13.449"/>
                                                    <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle_33" Width="84.9467" Height="16.0729" Canvas.Left="14.6786" Canvas.Top="-7.12276e-005" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1.6" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000"/>
                                                </Canvas>
                                            </Viewbox>
                                            <Viewbox x:Name="Group_34" Width="107.672" Height="16.0728" Margin="6,15,0,28">
                                                <Canvas Width="107.672" Height="16.0728">
                                                    <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle_35" Width="83.1734" Height="14.4729" Canvas.Left="8.84671" Canvas.Top="0.799988" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF733800"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_48" Width="36.1823" Height="4.64557" Canvas.Left="56.5044" Canvas.Top="6.83046" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB65900" Data="F1 M 92.3667,8.42389C 89.0508,8.42389 81.9392,8.47461 79.097,8.03613C 76.2547,7.5976 56.359,6.0625 56.8327,8.47467C 57.3064,10.8868 62.5172,11.3254 69.1491,11.1061C 75.781,10.8868 77.0348,10.33 92.1934,10.33"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_49" Width="39.3557" Height="7.285" Canvas.Left="53.1578" Canvas.Top="5.56276" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF4A2500" Data="F1 M 92.1934,7.211C 85.5615,7.211 78.6232,7.159 73.8862,6.2818C 69.1491,5.40472 52.5693,5.84326 53.5168,8.91327C 54.4642,11.9833 66.7806,12.8604 76.2547,12.4219C 85.7289,11.9833 84.6141,11.4969 92.1934,11.7162"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_50" Width="42.4594" Height="9.32973" Canvas.Left="49.8808" Canvas.Top="4.50859" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB65900" Data="F1 M 92.0202,5.47821C 83.9671,5.25885 67.2543,4.52753 61.5698,4.96613C 55.8853,5.40472 50.2008,6.93964 50.2008,8.69403C 50.2008,10.4482 59.2013,13.5182 64.4121,13.5183C 69.6229,13.5183 88.7042,12.7559 92.0202,12.7559"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_51" Width="6.85587" Height="2.21015" Canvas.Left="61.7233" Canvas.Top="7.91792" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB65900" Fill="#FF5B2D00" Data="F1 M 62.0433,9.57129C 62.0433,9.57129 63.2991,8.36212 63.9282,8.25555C 64.5573,8.14899 68.7999,8.53595 68.2016,9.13275C 67.6033,9.72943 62.0741,10.0615 62.0433,9.57129 Z "/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_52" Width="14.1696" Height="4.7466" Canvas.Left="33.6248" Canvas.Top="5.8024" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF5B2D00" Data="F1 M 41.6741,10.229C 43.1721,10.229 48.306,8.91327 47.3586,8.03613C 46.4112,7.159 40.253,5.62396 38.8318,6.2818C 37.4107,6.9397 33.0899,7.48016 34.0948,8.25543C 35.5159,9.35181 40.253,10.229 41.6741,10.229 Z "/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_53" Width="20.0949" Height="6.93487" Canvas.Left="29.4785" Canvas.Top="4.49127" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB65900" Data="F1 M 48.306,5.62396C 46.6338,5.10791 42.6215,4.52753 38.3581,4.96606C 34.0948,5.40472 29.3577,7.15894 29.8314,7.81683C 30.3051,8.47479 35.5159,11.1061 37.8844,11.1061C 40.253,11.1061 48.306,10.4482 48.7797,9.79047C 49.2534,9.13257 49.7271,6.06256 48.306,5.62396 Z "/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_54" Width="83.9867" Height="4.72039" Canvas.Left="8.52672" Canvas.Top="3.33039" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF4A2500" Data="F1 M 92.1934,4.43854C 89.3512,4 83.3603,3.65039 74.8336,3.65039C 66.3069,3.65039 53.9905,4.52753 52.5694,4.96613C 51.1482,5.40472 48.306,4.52753 46.8849,4.30829C 45.4638,4.08893 35.5159,3.86963 30.3051,5.40472C 25.0944,6.93976 28.3961,7.22699 13.7253,7.5976L 8.84673,7.73077"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_55" Width="83.4669" Height="6.91535" Canvas.Left="8.70001" Canvas.Top="8.11655" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF4A2500" Data="F1 M 91.8469,14.3154C 86.6361,14.5347 58.2538,15.4919 53.9905,13.299C 49.7271,11.1061 48.306,11.5447 44.5163,11.9833C 40.7267,12.4219 27.9365,10.4482 24.6206,9.13257C 21.3047,7.81689 9.02001,8.77051 9.02001,8.77051"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_56" Width="83.6401" Height="4.56678" Canvas.Left="8.8733" Canvas.Top="2.04615" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB65900" Data="F1 M 92.1934,3.05231C 81.7719,2.61377 57.7801,1.67676 53.5168,3.65039C 49.2534,5.62396 49.2534,1.01898 36.937,2.77325C 24.6206,4.52759 25.0943,6.2818 18.9361,6.2818C 12.7779,6.28192 9.19327,6.34454 9.1933,6.17133"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_57" Width="44.3626" Height="5.48686" Canvas.Left="8.52672" Canvas.Top="9.44783" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB65900" Data="F1 M 52.5693,14.6147C 52.5693,14.6147 50.2008,12.4218 46.8849,12.8604C 43.5689,13.299 24.6206,10.8868 21.7784,10.229C 18.9361,9.57123 8.84673,9.81012 8.84673,9.81012"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_58" Width="15.458" Height="2.02624" Canvas.Left="76.8822" Canvas.Top="0.479741" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF4A2500" Data="F1 M 92.0202,2.18597C 89.1779,2.18597 77.2022,0.799744 77.2022,0.799744"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_59" Width="23.0458" Height="5.0448" Canvas.Left="8.52674" Canvas.Top="0.479619" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF4A2500" Data="F1 M 31.2525,0.799622C 31.2525,0.799622 21.7783,4.74683 18.9361,4.74683C 16.0939,4.74683 14.5312,5.61621 8.84674,4.95831"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_60" Width="10.5879" Height="3.27147" Canvas.Left="8.66824" Canvas.Top="0.479619" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB25700" Data="F1 M 18.9361,0.799622C 18.9361,0.799622 16.5676,3.21173 8.98824,3.43109"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_61" Width="37.257" Height="4.25008" Canvas.Left="8.52672" Canvas.Top="11.1232" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF4A2500" Data="F1 M 45.4637,15.0533C 45.4637,15.0533 36.4633,13.9568 31.2525,13.0797C 26.0417,12.2026 14.5312,11.1043 8.84673,11.543"/>
                                                    <Path x:Name="Path_62" Width="13.0979" Height="2.68291" Canvas.Left="8.52674" Canvas.Top="13.129" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="0.640004" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FFB65900" Data="F1 M 21.3046,15.4919C 21.3046,15.4919 17.3735,13.449 8.84674,13.449"/>
                                                    <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle_51" Width="84.9467" Height="16.0729" Canvas.Left="8.04671" Canvas.Top="-1.01924e-005" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1.6" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000"/>
                                                </Canvas>
                                            </Viewbox>

                                        </Grid>
                                    </Viewbox>
                            </Grid>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

## Another Project

Using the above code in other projects does not always give the same error, adding to the wonder of the error.

Tried to create a completely new project and only reusing the code, but the invalid xaml persists. But still compiles and deploys fine :/

## Initial Solution

We have used a package from NuGet, about blend.expression.sdk, this package introduces the errors. But it was needed since one of the computers does not receive the references during install of blend or visual studio.

Comment: the XAML designer is not very good, in my project it breaks half the times no matter what the XAML looks like

Answer (score 1):

In my experience with Visual Studio 2013/15 the XAML designer, seemingly at random, will throw an "Invalid Markup" message or simply never load -- despite the application compiling and running perfectly well.

Restarting Visual Studio has always fixed this problem for me.

If the designer won't display a preview after a restart... I recommend commenting out elements from your markup until it succeeds. Or, alternatively, create a new, blank page which previews correctly and add one element at a time until it either 1) matches one of your examples or 2) suddenly fails (in which case you've found the offending element).

Comment: I upvoted you, but the simplified and concise answer could have been "WPF is bad; don't use it."